# Pass an updated function to an existing function

Tags: function, julia

In this short sequence, the user creates a function `userfunc()`, but then wants to update the first definition to do something different. However the `programfunc()` has already compiled the first version, and continues to use it.

```
userfunc(str, n) = str ^ n
userfunc("hello", 3)

"hellohellohello"

# program makes use of the user's function
programfunc(func, a, b) = func(a, b)
programfunc(userfunc, "hello", 3)

"hellohellohello"

# now the user redefines the function
userfunc(str, n) = str ^ (n * n)
# userfunc("hello", 3) give "hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello"

# but program still makes use of the first userfunc()
programfunc(userfunc, "hello", 3)

"hellohellohello"
```

So how could `programfunc()` be defined so that it always uses the latest definition of the function passed to it?

Comment: [related issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/265#issuecomment-242102435)

Comment: @GnimucK. Ah, that's #265 from 2011. Fixed for 0.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`invoke` will do it. (Note though this will probably not compile to nice specialized code)

The issue here is that julia specialized on Type.
That is to say it compiles a custom version of the function for every combination of types passed to it.
Since Functions have a type in julia 0.5 
(Each function is a singleton type.)
that causes it to specialize on the function

tested on 0.5-rc0

```
julia> userfunc(str, n) = str ^ (n*n)
WARNING: Method definition userfunc(Any, Any) in module Main at REPL[16]:1 overwritten at REPL[20]:1.
userfunc (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function programfunc(func, a, b)
       invoke(func, (typeof(a), typeof(b)), a, b)
       end
programfunc (generic function with 1 method)

julia> programfunc(userfunc, "hello", 3)
"hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello"

julia> userfunc(str, n) = str ^ (n)
WARNING: Method definition userfunc(Any, Any) in module Main at REPL[16]:1 overwritten at REPL[20]:1.
userfunc (generic function with 1 method)

julia> programfunc(userfunc, "hello", 3)
"hellohellohello"
```

Note this also works around [#265](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/265)

```
julia> foo(x)=2*x
foo (generic function with 1 method)


julia> function g(x)
       invoke(foo, (typeof(x),), x)
       end
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g(2)
4

julia> foo(x)=3*x
WARNING: Method definition foo(Any) in module Main at REPL[1]:1 overwritten at REPL[10]:1.
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g(2)
6
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple workaround is to use an anonymous function:

```
programfunc((x,y) -> userfunc(x,y), "hello", 3)
```

This works because a new anonymous function is created each time:

```
julia> f(x) = x
x -> f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x -> f(x)
(::#15) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x -> f(x)
(::#17) (generic function with 1 method)
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I declare a function to later accept an unnamed function, though?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can pass an anonymous function as an argument to another function anywhere you would pass a "normal" function. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: In other words, you do not change anything in the original function, but rather at the moment when you call it.

Comment: I think I meant, how do you specify the 'passed' function arguments and types in the original function definition. Eg how do I specify the arguments of `ufunc` in `function programfunc(ufunc, a, b) ... end`.

Comment: You don't specify them there. You use it just like you originally wrote. The problem is that when you later pass in the anonymous function; at that moment you have to pass in enough parameters. (Or do a splat.)