# Function argument passing and function redefinition in Julia

Tags: julia

When I redefine a function that has been passed into another function, it seems the redefinition was not passed into that function.

```
 function foo(f)
        f(3)
    end

f(x)=x

foo(f) #=>3

f(x)=x*x

foo(f) #=>3

f(3) #=>9
```

This behavior looks so weird to me. What's the logic behind this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass an updated function to an existing function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057740/pass-an-updated-function-to-an-existing-function)

Comment: Running `f(x)=x*x` prompts a `definition overwritten` warning. The warning alerts to the possibility of this kind of behavior. In general, redefining functions when some other functions referencing it have already been compiled is tricky. As https://github.com/julialang/julia/issues/265 from 2011 indicates, this is an old issue, but I guess programs can be refactored to avoid this issue.

Comment: @DanGetz, you should just post that as an answer.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that 265 was fixed in v0.6, so in a few weeks this will just be a non-issue for most users. Maybe an answer should make sure to say that?

Comment: "but I guess programs can be refactored to avoid this issue." just use anonymous functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `f(x)=x*x` prompts a `definition overwritten` warning. The warning alerts to the possibility of this kind of behavior. In general, redefining functions when some other functions referencing it have already been compiled is tricky. As http://github.com/julialang/julia/issues/265 from 2011 indicates, this is an old issue.

A program can avoid this issue with care. For example, using anonymous functions with `foo()` in the question will give:

```
julia> foo(x->x)
3
julia> foo(x->x*x)
9
```

**In Julia 0.6 this issue is resolved**. The Github issue details the resolution, but essentially, Julia keeps track of a version number of the world, and a function 'sees' a certain version of the world. In  the REPL, a redefinition causes the call to the older function to trigger a recompile (see http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods.html# for details). The resulting behavior is less weird:

```
julia> # version 6.0
julia> function foo(f)
       f(3)
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)
julia> f(x)=x
f (generic function with 1 method)
julia> foo(f)
3
julia> f(x)=x*x
f (generic function with 1 method)    
julia> foo(f)
9
julia> # :-)
```

*Thanks to @StefanKarpinski, @ChrisRackauckas*